# How to properly use passport-oauth2 for using Twitter Oauth2 auth service?

Tags: twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0, passport.js

As **`passport-twitter`** still goes for OAuth v1, I decided to try with **`passport-oauth2`** to accomplish Twitter login with out sessions for my app.

This is what I tried:

```
passport.use(new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate',
    tokenURL: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
    clientID: process.env.TWITTER_FINALCUT_CONSUMER_KEY,
    clientSecret: process.env.TWITTER_FINALCUT_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:9248/auth/login/redirect/tw'
    },
    function (access_token,refreshToken,profile,done) {
        console.log(accessToken,Object.keys(profile));
        return done(null, profile, {tokens: {accessToken: accessToken, refreshToken: refreshToken}});
}));
```

However when reaching the url for starting the auth process, I'm redirected to this Twitter screen. I can't figure out what's wrong with what I'm doing.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: How have you solved it?

Comment: OAuth 2.0 authentication requires session support when using state. If state is not supplied, it throws error saying AuthorizationError: You need to pass the "state" parameter
   at OAuth2Strategy.authenticate . So, passport doesn't support sessionless authentication using oauth2 or other strategies like passport-linkedin-oauth2.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the strategy would be the same as for e.g.
https://github.com/Slotos/passport-reddit/blob/master/lib/passport-reddit/strategy.js

The Problem is not with Passport JS itself but with the underlying module "node-oauth". So please see especially the "To comply we are resorting to overriding" comment in the strategy above.

I would prefer if it would be fixed in the module and so I just commented here : https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth/issues/300

When this is resolved I would like to contribute it directly to the twitter strategy as an OAuth2 strategy.

The overriding step for twitter would basically be [for now, until above is resolved] :

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var OAuth2 = require('oauth').OAuth2;
OAuth2.prototype.getOAuthAccessToken = function(code, params, callback) {
  var params= params || {};
  params['client_id'] = this._clientId;
  params['client_secret'] = this._clientSecret;
  var codeParam = (params.grant_type === 'refresh_token') ? 'refresh_token' : 'code';
  params[codeParam]= code;

  var post_data= querystring.stringify( params );
  var post_headers= {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
  };
  if (params.hasOwnProperty('headers') && typeof params.headers === 'object') {
    for (var key in params.headers) {
      post_headers[key] = params.headers[key];
    }
  }

  this._request("POST", this._getAccessTokenUrl() || 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token' /* TODO */, post_headers, post_data, null, function(error, data, response) {
    if( error )  callback(error);
    else {
      var results;
      try {
        // As of http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-07
        // responses should be in JSON
        results= JSON.parse( data );
      }
      catch(e) {
        // .... However both Facebook + Github currently use rev05 of the spec
        // and neither seem to specify a content-type correctly in their response headers :(
        // clients of these services will suffer a *minor* performance cost of the exception
        // being thrown
        results= querystring.parse( data );
      }
      var access_token= results["access_token"];
      var refresh_token= results["refresh_token"];
      delete results["refresh_token"];
      callback(null, access_token, refresh_token, results); // callback results =-=
    }
  });
}
```

and could be used in a strategy as

```
var s64 = new Buffer(
  [encodeURIComponent(process.env.CONSUMER_KEY),':',
  encodeURIComponent(process.env.CONSUMER_SECRET)].join('')
).toString('base64');
OAuth2.prototype.getOAuthAccessToken('', {
  grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  headers: {
    Authorization: ['Basic', s64].join(' ')
  }
},
function(e, access_token, refresh_token, res) {
  console.log(e, access_token, refresh_token, res);
});
```